# change color of pages

Tags: windows-7, windows

I currently use Firefox on an Acer laptop with Windows 7. I don't know what happened, but my pages are no longer white. They all have an aqua background now with pink borders and pink is background color for message boxes. This is affecting my pictures now. Pictures are distorted with red running through them. How do I get my white pages back? Please keep in mind that I am technically challenged, so make it easy for me.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Are these problems only occurring in Firefox or is it all applications. I am asking because if the pictures are distorted, that tends to point to a graphics card/cable problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `Theme` enabled. If you click on the `Firefox Tab` on the top left and then on the `Add-ons` option you should be presented with the `Add-on Manager` page where you can enable and disable add-ons. From the menu on the left click on `Appearance` and check if you have any themes installed. If you do, simply click on the `Disable` option, which should remove the theme.

I have provided screen-shots for clarification.

[image: Add-ons]

Here's what the `Add-on Manager` page should look like:

[image]